# "requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))"

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, python-requests, response

I'm trying to connect to https://apis.digital.gob.cl/fl/feriados/2020, but I get an `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))` error on a script that works perfectly with other URLs.

The code:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://apis.digital.gob.cl/fl/feriados/2020')
print(response.status_code)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The issue is that the website filters out requests without a proper `User-Agent`, so just use a random one from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent#examples_2):

```py
requests.get("https://apis.digital.gob.cl/fl/feriados/2020", headers={
"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the augmented user agent string! A simple agent string like `{'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0'}` doesn't get accepted by some websites.

Comment: If it still doesn't work, check the User-Agent string of your current browser (there are websites which tell you what it is) and try that.

Answer (score 2):

It might be due to idle timeout. Overriding default socket options can help

```
import socket
from urllib3.connection import HTTPConnection

HTTPConnection.default_socket_options = (
    HTTPConnection.default_socket_options + [
        (socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 1),
        (socket.SOL_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPIDLE, 45),
        (socket.SOL_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPINTVL, 10),
        (socket.SOL_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPCNT, 6)
    ]
)
```